# Java Incomparable Data types char and String

Tags: java

When I run the Javac, it tells me that i have an incomparable data types char and String in the

```
while(responseChar == "y")
```

not sure what to change to fix this error

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class UseOrder
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int answer, num, q;
    String name, response;
    double p;
    char responseChar;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    Order order1 = new Order();
    order1.setCustomerName();
    order1.setCustomerNum();
    order1.setQuantity();
    order1.setUnitPrice();
    order1.computePrice();
    order1.displayInfo();

    keyboard.nextLine(); 
    System.out.println("Do you need the shipping and handling service?");
    System.out.println("Enter y or n :");
    response = keyboard.nextLine();
    responseChar = response.charAt(0);
    while(responseChar == "y")
    {
        ShippedOrder order2 = new ShippedOrder();
        order2.getCustomerName();
        order2.getCustomerNum();
        order2.getQuantity();
        order2.getUnitPrice();
        order2.computePrice();
        order2.displayInfo();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 20):

To define a character literal, use a single quote: `'`. Double quotes define string literals.

```
while(responseChar == 'y')
```

Answer (score 3):

Optionally you could use the big C `Character` class to convert your `char` to a `String`:

```
String converted = Character.toString(responseChar); 
while(converted.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
{
  // ...
}
```

But this version is much more verbose than the literal comparison suggested by Jeffrey

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response.  It compiled as soon as I changed the " to a ".  I did however run into a new problem.  When I ran the program and entered y for the shipping and handling question, it just keeps repeating
customer name :null
customer number :0
Orer quantity :0
Order price : 0
Shipped price 4.0
total price :0

Comment: Set some real value to the object like order1.setCustomerName("John Doe");  And also implement some mechanism to break the while loop . If you were expecting to print it only once, you can add break; at the end of the while block. ie after order2.displayInfo();

Comment: @Nate You should probably pass the `Order` object to the `ShippedOrder` constructor so you can get all of those values that you set above: `ShippedOrder order2 = new ShippedOrder(order1);`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `"y"` do this `'y'`.  `""` Represents string.